# HEAD requests with aiohttp is dog slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Given a list of 50k websites urls, I've been tasked to find out which of them are up/reachable. The idea is just to send a `HEAD` request to each URL and look at the status response. From what I hear an asynchronous approach is the way to go and for now I'm using `asyncio` with `aiohttp`.

I came up with the following code but the speed is pretty abysmal. 1000 URLs takes approximately 200 seconds on my 10mbit connection. I don't know what speeds to expect but I'm new to asynchronous programming in Python so I figured I've stepped wrong somewhere. As you can see I've tried increasing the number of allowed simultaneous connections to 1000 (up from the default of 100) and the duration for which DNS resolves are kept in the cache; neither to any great effect. The environment has Python 3.6 and  `aiohttp` 3.5.4.

Code review unrelated to the question is also appreciated.

```
import asyncio
import time
from socket import gaierror
from typing import List, Tuple

import aiohttp
from aiohttp.client_exceptions import TooManyRedirects

# Using a non-default user-agent seems to avoid lots of 403 (Forbidden) errors
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
                   'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                   'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),
}


async def get_status_code(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str) -> Tuple[int, str]:
    try:
        # A HEAD request is quicker than a GET request
        resp = await session.head(url, allow_redirects=True, ssl=False, headers=HEADERS)
        async with resp:
            status = resp.status
            reason = resp.reason
        if status == 405:
            # HEAD request not allowed, fall back on GET
            resp = await session.get(
                url, allow_redirects=True, ssl=False, headers=HEADERS)
            async with resp:
                status = resp.status
                reason = resp.reason
        return (status, reason)
    except aiohttp.InvalidURL as e:
        return (900, str(e))
    except aiohttp.ClientConnectorError:
        return (901, "Unreachable")
    except gaierror as e:
        return (902, str(e))
    except aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError as e:
        return (903, str(e))
    except aiohttp.ClientOSError as e:
        return (904, str(e))
    except TooManyRedirects as e:
        return (905, str(e))
    except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as e:
        return (906, str(e))
    except aiohttp.ServerTimeoutError:
        return (907, "Connection timeout")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return (908, "Connection timeout")


async def get_status_codes(loop: asyncio.events.AbstractEventLoop, urls: List[str],
                           timeout: int) -> List[Tuple[int, str]]:
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000, ttl_dns_cache=300)
    client_timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(connect=timeout)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            loop=loop, timeout=client_timeout, connector=conn) as session:
        codes = await asyncio.gather(*(get_status_code(session, url) for url in urls))
        return codes


def poll_urls(urls: List[str], timeout=20) -> List[Tuple[int, str]]:
    """
    :param timeout: in seconds
    """
    print("Started polling")
    time1 = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    codes = loop.run_until_complete(get_status_codes(loop, urls, timeout))
    time2 = time.time()
    dt = time2 - time1
    print(f"Polled {len(urls)} websites in {dt:.1f} seconds "
          f"at {len(urls)/dt:.3f} URLs/sec")
    return codes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you're launching all your requests at once. Thus probably bottleneck appeared somewhere. To avoid this situation [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) can be used:

```
# code

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(200)


async def get_status_code(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str) -> Tuple[int, str]:
    try:
        async with sem:
            resp = await session.head(url, allow_redirects=True, ssl=False, headers=HEADERS)
            # code
```

I tested it following way:

```
poll_urls([
    'http://httpbin.org/delay/1' 
    for _ 
    in range(2000)
])
```

And got:

```
Started polling
Polled 2000 websites in 13.2 seconds at 151.300 URLs/sec
```

Although it requests a single host, it shows that asynchronous approach does the job: 13 sec. < 2000 sec.

Several more things can be done:

- You should play semaphore value to achieve better performance
  for your concrete environment and task.
- Try to lower timeout from `20` to, let's say, `5`
  seconds: since you're just doing head request it shouldn't take much
  time. If request hangs for 5 seconds there are good chances it won't
  be successful at all.
- Monitoring your system resources (network/CPU/RAM) while script running
  can help to find out if bottleneck is still present.
- By the way, did you install `aiodns` (as [doc](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#library-installation) suggests)?
- Does [disabling ssl](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets) change anything?
- Try to enable debug level of [logging](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/logging.html) to see if there is any useful info there
- Try to setup [client tracing](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-tracing) and especially measure time for each request step to see which ones take most time

It's difficult to say more without fully reproducible situation.

Comment: Given that there's only a single eventloop on a single thread, is not using a semaphore of 200 the same as just initializing with `aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=200)`? I'm getting 60 URLs/sec on polling httbin, which is low but wtihin range I suppose, but 10 URLs/sec (up from 5/sec since I'm also using `sock_read=20` timeout) when using my own data. I don't understand why there's a difference if I'm launching all requests at one. I've played around with the aforementioned limit and there's no significant difference between 200 and 1K given a list of 1K URLs.

Comment: To add, there's no significant load on my system. CPU cores stay below 20 %; no ram usage, up/down network speed below 70kb/s. I tried lowering both `sock_read` and `sock_connect` down from 20 sec to 5, but the speed on my own URLs is exactly the same, around 10/sec while the httpbin is around 120/sec. So httbin reacts to lower timeouts but my data (which has lots of difference errors, such as 404, reset by peer, unreachable, forbidden, what have you) does not.

Comment: `is not using a semaphore of 200 the same as just initializing with aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=200)?` - can't say for sure, but intuition says that it's better not to start request before we want instead of relaying on underlying aiohttp connection pool. For example, without semaphore when DNS resolving timeout starts - when `session.head` invoked or when connection actually available? With semaphore you can be sure if won't start too soon. ||| I also updated answer with few more options you can try.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I looked at the code.  Shouldn't you be reading in a list of URLs, probably from a CSV, or text file?  I don't see any way to scan through a list of URLs scan.  How is that done?  Thanks.

Comment: @asher urls are plain string and shouldn't [take too much RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445244/1113207) unless you have billions of them. But if this is the case, then yes, you should read them from storage on demand. I would say DB will fit most, asyncio [has some drivers](https://github.com/timofurrer/awesome-asyncio#database-drivers). Reading from CSV or other file can be done with some [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) wrapper, but it'll be more complicated and less efficient than DB.

Comment: Thanks.  So, when I run the OPs code, I can see it do something, but it doesn't seem to do anything useful.  I don't see how it is reading through a list of URLs and I don't see any message printed in the console, so there doesn't seem to be any confirmation of any work being done.  Am I missing something or is this the expected result?

Comment: @asher OPs code prints results of its work once finished. Take a look at second print inside `poll_urls`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `headers` and `ssl` parameters to each request, add them to `ClientSession` and `TCPConnector` constructors respectively. This may help to increase your code speed slightly. Below is the changed code:

```
async def get_status_code(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str) -> Tuple[int, str]:
    try:
        # A HEAD request is quicker than a GET request
        resp = await session.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
...

async def get_status_codes(loop: asyncio.events.AbstractEventLoop, urls: List[str],
                           timeout: int) -> List[Tuple[int, str]]:
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000, ttl_dns_cache=300, ssl=False)
    client_timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(connect=timeout)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            loop=loop, timeout=client_timeout, connector=conn, headers=headers) as session:
...
```