# What are the full range of values for str, double, and complex including their size in memory?

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Basic data types: Python basic data types with their range of values provided in the following table.]

I don't know the range for double, complex, str, and the size for all the data types I can't find any information on the web; when I use **getsizeof()** it gives me a large number because it has something to do with the added overhead, and there was another function that ignored said overhead but the size is still big: and, I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by the size of `str`? The maximal length of a string?

Comment: the amount of space in bytes a single character string would take in memory

Comment: [This may answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445201/python-size-of-strings-in-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python integer numbers have unlimited range (see also `sys.int_info`). The range of floating-point numbers can be found in `sys.float_info`. There are no double numbers in Python. Complex numbers are represented as pairs of floating-point numbers.